# How to pass multiple button click variable to next page in jQuery mobile?

Tags: php, jquery

How I can pass the variable on button click to next page in jQuery mobile?

```
<div class="left_container w3-ul w3-card-4">
    <div class="post-meta">
        <h4 style="text-align:left;padding-top:5px;margin-left:20px;">Engineering</h4>
    </div>
    <ul>

        <li><a href="dept.php?dep=Civil&page=1">Civil</a></li>
        <li><a href="dept.php?dep=Chemical&page=1">Chemical</a></li>
        <li><a href="dept.php?dep=Computer&page=1">Computer</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: **First Way** Bind click event on links, intercept, manual redirect.
**Second Way** On page load update the links `href` attribute to add the query params

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're completely reloading the page you'd have to intercept the click event and redirect manually.  Something like

```
$(".post-meta a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  //Stop the link from firing normally.
    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    location += "&var1=" + var1 + "&var2=" + var2;
    window.location = location;
});
```

If the existing link doesn't have query vars you'd prefix with `?` instead of `&`.  You could do a basic substring check to see which prefix you should use.  Since you're example already has a query var on every , I'm assuming you can assume you'll always have one?